# apache .htaccess ssl to only one site

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file for some domains sitting on same folder but leads to different content that is determined by php according to the domain name.

I want only one of them to redirect all requests to ssl domain.

How that's can be done?

When I use redirect rules it transfer all domains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip `mydomain.com` from this `http->https` redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```